# Groovy/Spock: specify which values are passed into a closure of a mock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

first of all, this is my first day with spock, so please be patient with me ;-).

How do I set up expectations for the following class under test?

```
class JobThing {
    Logger log;

    void loppy(Sql sql) {
        sql.eachRow("select x from y") {
            z -> log.info("${z.x}")
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to pretend that the select statement returns "a" then "b".
This is what I've come up with

```
def "loppy"() {
    setup:
    def job = new JobThing()
    job.log = Mock(Logger)
    Sql sql = Mock(Sql)

    when:
    job.loppy(sql)

    then:
    //if sql.eachRow(...) is called then call its closure with value "a" then value "b"
    1 * sql.eachRow('select x from y') {
        // declare expected values here? or where?
    }
    1 * job.log.info("a")
    1 * job.log.info("b")
}
```

This is just one of many variants I've come up with... none worked until now. Docs do not help much since I do not seem to find good keywords to search for.

Thanks

Comment: You did mock of sql object and haven't defined behaviour for eachRow method. Don't expect that mock going to know by itself what to do.
But even if you had have defined (mocked) the method you would have tested mock instead of the implementation - which is rather pointless.
You may try using Spy instead of Mock but at this time your implementation has not 'tes-friendly' design.

Comment: how would I define the behaviour of the Sql.eachRow? I found a lot of examples telling me how to define the return value, but how do I define what gets passed into the closure on the first, second, third call? Could you please provide the required code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to think what are you about to test. "Loppy" doesn't seem to be explicit enough.
I'm not sure so just roughly speaking, split your test into two feature methods like this:

```
class JobThingSpec extends Specification {

    def sql = Mock(Sql)
    def log = Mock(Logger)
    def job = new JobThing(log: log)

    def 'proper query is executed'() {
        when:
        job.loppy(sql)

        then:
        1 * sql.eachRow('select x from y', _)

    }

    def 'query result is logged'() {
        given:
        sql.rows(_) >> [[x:'a'], [x:'b']]

        when:
        job.loppy(sql)

        then:
        1 * log.info('a')
        1 * log.info('b')
    }
}
```

This way you have your case nicely decomposed into separate test steps - which is better by itself (readability, test fail feedback).

Moreover you don't have to worry about the passed Closure as it is not easy to test and in your case quite pointless. But if you still need that let me know and we can find out a way.

UPDATE:

Just adjust your method like this:

```
void loppy(Sql sql) {
    List<Map> result = sql.rows("select x from y")
    result.each { z ->
        log.info("${z.x}")
    }
}
```

Comment: your 2nd method fails because sql.eachRow(String, Closure) returns void

    Cannot cast object '[{x=a}, {x=b}]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'void' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: void(java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap)

Comment: You're right, sorry I was writing the example without executing it. Just decompose implementation of loppy method into two steps, then things get easier. I updated example of the test and added altered loppy method as well.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear about my point: I need to figure out how to test the closure when using `sql.eachRow` since _I cannot change the loppy method_. It is not my code, but I need to test it! I never thought this could be hard at all. Is there a way to do it easily with any of the other groovy mocking frameworks? As far as I understood, spock is not tied to its own mocking framework.

Comment: Closure is anonymous function. I don't think there is a way to unit-test posted implementation without refactoring. You can check interaction for Sql object like this `1 * sql.eachRow('select x from y', _)`, which means call without 2nd argument specified. If you write Closure in the test it will fail in two ways: 1st. the interaction as the Closure instance won't be the same; 2nd. you would be testing mock anyway instead of the implementation. You can either refactor or use integration test (unless you are willing to mock Sql's underlying DataSource, but this seems ridiculous)